# How to create a filter to display custom post types

Tags: wordpress, filter, filtering, taxonomy

I have a custom post type 'projects' and have an overview page that displays these post types with featured image & post title. I have also created a custom taxonomy for that Post Type and assigned the posts to the categories from that taxonomy.

What I want to achieve now is that on the Overview Page where all the posts are listed, above them should be something like a filter bar with the custom taxonomy categories displayed.

My question now is: What WordPress functions do I need so that when someone clicks on one of the categories, only the posts assigned to that category will be displayed? I don't want the page to refresh or load another page. Here is an example of what I want to achieve: https://www.hauserlacour.de/en/work

Also, I am not a coder. I use Pinegrow to convert my static html sites to a wordpress theme. but in Pinegrow I have the option of a lot of WP function. That's why I just need to understand how the set up of something like above would work.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you know a bit more about the the `WP_Query` you can use the `tax_query` as below:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => array( 'project_cat' ), // <-- NO! Does not work.
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'project_cat1', 'project_cat2')
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_tax_query/

or you can simply list the taxonomy terms and simply redirect to taxonomy detail page where respective projects will be listed automatically.

```
$args = array( 'hide_empty=0' );
 
$terms = get_terms( 'my_term', $args );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    $count = count( $terms );
    $i = 0;
    $term_list = '<p class="my_term-archive">';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $i++;
        $term_list .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain' ), $term->name ) ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
        if ( $count != $i ) {
            $term_list .= ' &middot; ';
        }
        else {
            $term_list .= '</p>';
        }
    }
    echo $term_list;
}
```

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

Comment: Hi @Gorakh_sth, thank you for your answer! I believe I can add custom code in Pinegrow. So, the first option you mentioned, that is all the code I would need to achieve the filter? Obviously would have to swap out the custom post type and custom taxonomy name, but then it should work?

Comment: I tried but the code isn't working. My understanding is also that this would need be an Ajax request

Comment: @JanaLux Yes,  if you want to use ajax you need to do ajax request and that above WP_Query should be inside the ajax action function. Or you can simple submit the the form and get categories selected and pass it to the WP_Query.